# SQL - CASE WHEN Statement, Not fully working

Tags: sql, sql-server

Morning Everyone.

Just to start of with that im very new to SQL and im still in the learning stage.

I'm getting quite frustrated with what i thought was a simple "CASE WHEN" statement.

I'm currently trying to pull all the different attributes types for 1 location into a Yes or No (Blank Field) format.

[image: SQL_Image]

Screenshot attached of the SQL Diagram Pane, Criteria Pane, SQL Pane and Results.

SQL CODE:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                         TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.ih_location.place_ref, dbo.co_place.address##1, dbo.co_place.address##2, dbo.ih_location.location_type, 

CASE WHEN (dbo.ih_loc_attr.attrib_code = '10%T') THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END AS [10%T], 
CASE WHEN (dbo.ih_loc_attr.attrib_code = 'EPCB') THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END AS EPCB, CASE WHEN (dbo.ih_loc_attr.attrib_code = 'GR1') THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END AS GR1, 
CASE WHEN (dbo.ih_loc_attr.attrib_code = 'SAP') THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END AS SAP, CASE WHEN (dbo.ih_loc_attr.attrib_code = 'SOCH') THEN 'Yes' ELSE '' END AS SOCH, dbo.ih_loc_attr.attrib_code

FROM          
  dbo.co_place LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.ih_loc_attr ON dbo.co_place.place_ref = dbo.ih_loc_attr.place_ref RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.ih_location ON dbo.co_place.place_ref = dbo.ih_location.place_ref

WHERE       
(dbo.ih_location.place_ref = '00010001')

ORDER BY
dbo.ih_location.place_ref
```

As you will see i have this appearing on 6 different lines. Ideally i would like this to show on 1 line but in different column headers.

[image: Results]

I hope what i have said makes sense.

Any help on this would be amazing.

Many Thanks
Stewart

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? That query looks more like SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry i have now amended that.

Comment: I think you need to go with your query, "The Shorter The Better" is not always the case

Answer (score 2):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT l.place_ref, p.address##1, p.address##2, l.location_type, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN la.attrib_code = '10%T' THEN 'Yes' END) AS [10%T], 
       MAX(CASE WHEN la.attrib_code = 'EPCB' THEN 'Yes' END) AS EPCB,
       MAX(CASE WHEN la.attrib_code = 'GR1' THEN 'Yes' END) AS GR1, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN la.attrib_code = 'SAP' THEN 'Yes' END) AS SAP,
       MAX(CASE WHEN la.attrib_code = 'SOCH' THEN 'Yes' END) AS SOCH    
FROM dbo.co_place p LEFT OUTER JOIN
     dbo.ih_loc_attr la
     ON p.place_ref =ila.place_ref RIGHT OUTER JOIN
     dbo.ih_location l
     ON p.place_ref = l.place_ref
WHERE l.place_ref = '00010001'
GROUP BY l.place_ref, p.address##1, p.address##2, l.location_type;
```

Notes:

- Use table aliases, they make the query easier to write and to read.
- I don't recommend `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, but I didn't fix that part of the query.
- The `ELSE ''` is unnecessary.  Just use `NULL` values and let the aggregation take care of the logic.
- I'm not sure if the other columns are appropriate in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Beat me to it Gordan. Clearly seems that the OP has a one-to-many relationship and they were expecting the query to "automagically" aggregate their data. :)